# Copying out color theme background from SQL management studio to Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, sql-server, sql-management-studio

I have a color theme set in SMS 2012, where the background is dark and some of the syntax is white, when I copy and paste this out into an email (white background) the dark background of management studio is not copied with it, meaning you can't see the text you copy/paste. Does anyone know if there is a setting that controls this?

Answer (score 1):

+1 for using dark scheme. Now the challenge with sharing your code with others. I'm not aware of a way to copy dark background, so I use two trick depending on situation.

1. Paste my query into LINQPad that I always have open for running stuff outside of SSMS, than select all, copy and paste into Outlook. Thus people see usual colors that they are used it.
2. When pasting into Outlook from SSMS, go to "Paste" Option and select "Paste Special" on the screen select "Unformatted Unicode text". You done, people want see pretty colors but they can take it and paste into their own environment.